# I still meet this problem

Tags: bootnodes

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/20351

Is this problem fixed??

geth 1.9.8

Comment: If you still have the same issue with the latest version I'd suggest to create a new issue and provide as much information as possible. The issue you referring has been closed without more feedback from the initial reporter.